# Scraping data from a wiki category with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve DOTA character names from `https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Category:Counters`.

I have tried the code below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Category:Counters').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
link = soup.find('div', class_="mw-category")

for link in link:
    link = link.text
    print(link)
```

I need the character (heroes as they are called in DOTA2) names only in a list form. Feel free to try this code yourself and check the output.

Comment: The intro tour includes the formatting guide; we expect that you are familiar with it before posting.

Comment: Use the formatting function for code in the Stack Overflow editor to format it correctly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  "It doesn't work" and "feel free to try the code" is not what we expect for a Stack Overflow Question.

Comment: Can you add the list of names you expect to see to your question post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was giving the list of heroes as HeroName/Counter, I basically corrected it. heroes_names is the list you are looking for i believe

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Category:Counters').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
link = soup.find('div', class_="mw-category")

heroes_names = []

for link in link:
    link = link.text
    heroes = link.split("\n")

    for i in range(1,len(heroes)):
        heroname = heroes[i].split("/")[0]

        heroes_names.append(heroname)


for hero_name in heroes_names:
    print(hero_name)
```

Comment: Thank you sir , this helped a lot.

Comment: can you tell me what the last two lines of code are for ? they donot seem to make a difference to output

Comment: those two lines just prints the heroes' names. I used them for testing.